# React Redux - Single card(item) rerender in array of cards(items)

Tags: reactjs, redux

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({posts: state.profile.posts});


return (this.props.posts.map((album,i)=> 
            <div key={i.toString()}>
            <div onClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this, album)}>{album.id}</div>
         </div>)


onLikeClick(album) {
      const likeDetail = {
        user:userid,
        post:album.id,
      }
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({    
          count: !prevState.count
      }))
      this.props.addLike(likeDetail);
    }
```

How can i update single card modified in multiple cards using react-redux. please help..thanks in advance.

1 - I am getting array list this.props.posts
2 - When i click to like single post how can i re-render single card  without re-rendering whole card(array)

How can i update single card modified in multiple cards using react-redux. please help..thanks in advance.

1 - I am getting array list this.props.posts
2 - When i click to like single post how can i re-render single card  without re-rendering whole card(array)

[image: sample]

Comment: post some code and not screen shots, also its unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Do you see visible re-rendering of the list? If your Redux usage is correct React should only be updating the DOM for the single item that has changed.

Comment: Actually i want to know after like function in action , do i need to rerender that array in response of like?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier please have a look

Comment: If you want to redirect to next page than your list component will be unmounted and than on the separate Post Page(detail page) component you need to call a separate API which will fetch the particular post detail by ID in param props I think that should be the proper way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Based on code you provided
You need to make a separate Page Component like below

```
const album = {this.props};

return (
          <div>
           <div onClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this, album)}>{album.id}</div>
          </div>
       )


onLikeClick(album) {
      const likeDetail = {
        user:userid,
        post:album.id,
      }
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({    
          count: !prevState.count
      }))
      this.props.addLike(likeDetail);
    }
```

And you can call that from parent component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({posts: state.profile.posts});

return (this.props.posts.map((album,i)=> 
            <Post {...this.props} album={album} key={i}/>)
```

so whenever your child component State will be changed your parent component will not get affected and whole list won't re-rendered
Hope it helps!